# How to demolish skyscraper?

Tags: battlefield-4

In Battlefield 4 on map "Siege of Shanghai" there is skyscraper in center. By the end of "Conquest" round it usually destroyed. But every time I miss that moment.

What trigger destruction of this building? Is it time-based, or you can destroy it by hands?

Do I need to fire tank at it? Or 100 C4 charges? Shoulf I ram into it in chopper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 4 pillars on the front of the building which need to be destroyed. You can achieve this with RPGs, Tank shells, C4 and Missile emplacements. Also likely are Chopper rockets and IFV cannon, although I have not tested this.

The 4 pillars you need to destroy are the ones shown below. They already have some exposed reinforcement bars showing.
[image]

Each pillar takes 2x RPG shots to destroy, or 2x MBT rounds, or 2x TOW Stationary Emplacements or 5x C4 explosives. This be Beta values so this may change.

This is an "undamaged" pillar.
[image]

This is a "damaged" pillar.
[image]

This is a "destroyed" pillar. When all 4 look like this, it's time to GTFO.
[image]